# Format question in examclass

Tags: formatting, exam

I want to format all the questions and subquestions in bold.
`\qformat` only affects what's in front of the real text.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\begin{document}
    This should not be in bold
    \begin{questions}
        \question This is a question
        \begin{solution}
             This should not be in bold
        \end{solution}
        \begin{parts}
            \part This is a subquestion
        \end{parts}

        \question This is a second question
    \end{questions}
    This should not be in bold
\end{document}
```

I want `This is a question`, `This is a subquestion` and `This is a second question` in bold.

I have no idea of how to do this.

Comment: So, you want everything bold? Interesting choice. Put `\bfseries` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: No, I want the questions in bold, other text not.

Comment: Place `\bfseries` after `\begin{questions}`

Comment: Any idea how I can make the solutions not bold?

Comment: They aren't if you have just one `\bfseries` aat the beginning of the `questions`  environment.

Comment: The solutions are bold too, when I write `\begin{questions}\bfseries ... \end{questions}`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't lookk close enough. You can add `\mdsries` inside the solution environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\questions}{\par\fi\@doitem}{\par\fi\bfseries\@doitem}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\questions}{\par\fi\@doitem}{\par\fi\bfseries\@doitem}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\questions}{\par\fi\@doitem}{\par\fi\bfseries\@doitem}{}{}
\makeatother

\SolutionEmphasis{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

This should not be in bold
\begin{questions}
\show\question
  \question This is a question
  \begin{solution}
  This should not be in bold
  \end{solution}
  \begin{parts}
  \part This is a subquestion
  \end{parts}

  \question This is a second question
\end{questions}

This should not be in bold

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you only want the text of the question in boldface, here's a different set of patches.

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpretocmd{\item@points@pageinfo}{\normalfont}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\item@points@pageinfo}{\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother

\SolutionEmphasis{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

This should not be in bold
\begin{questions}
  \question[3] This is a question
  \begin{solution}
  This should not be in bold
  \end{solution}
  \begin{parts}
  \part This is a subquestion
  \end{parts}

  \question This is a second question
\end{questions}

This should not be in bold

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haven't checked the internals, but why not simply `\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\mdseries}` and `\AtBeginEnvironment{questions}{\bfseries}`?

Comment: @Johannes_B Maybe. But so ”Solution” would be medium series.

Comment: Really? I just tested this and the word `Solution:` is bold.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand{\boldquestion}[2][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
        \question \textbf{#2}%
    }{%
        \question[#1] \textbf{#2}%
    }%
}
```

Now it's possible to write:
`\boldquestion[points]{Title}` or `\boldquestion{Title}`