# How do I print all questions in bold face when using the exam class?

Tags: exam

The exams documentclass allows us to apply any formatting to all solutions. What should I do if I want to do something similar to all questions, like say print it in bold font?

e.g. The following (with `printanswers` set in the preamble)

```tex
\begin{questions}
\question This is a question.

\begin{solution}
And its answer
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
```

should produce

[image]

Comment: could this post help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273677/format-question-in-examclass

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That's what I was looking for. Don't know why it didn't show up in any of my searches.